# Need to join two dataframes in R and combine data

Tags: r, join, merge

I'm having this issue:
I have to different dataframes for two bird count points from different days. I need to combine the dataframes and also, the names of the columns of the different dataframes do not match. My data frames are like this:

df1

| Especies | Conteo |
| --- | --- |
| (Crypturellus tataupa) | 1 |
| (Piaya cayana) | 2 |

df2

| Species | Count |
| --- | --- |
| (Crypturellus tataupa) | 3 |
| (Celeus flavescens) | 1 |

I have tried the whole set of `merge`, and was not what I needed.

And I need two different outputs:

-a complete merged where I end up having a full count of every specie

| Species | Count |
| --- | --- |
| (Crypturellus tataupa) | 4 |
| (Piaya cayana) | 2 |
| (Celeus flavescens) | 1 |

-a merged of the species merged and different columns for each count

| Especies | Count1 | Count2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Crypturellus tataupa) | 1 | 3 |
| (Piaya cayana) | 2 | 0 |
| (Celeus flavescens) | 0 | 1 |

As you can probably tell, I don't have a lot of experience in R. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below to obtain `out1` and `out2`, respectively

```
# initial merged output
out <- merge(
  df1,
  df2,
  by.x = "Especies",
  by.y = "Species",
  all = TRUE
)

# first output
out1 <- transform(
  out,
  Count = rowSums(out[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
)[-2]

# second output
out2 <- cbind(
  out[1],
  setNames(
    replace(out[-1], is.na(out[-1]), 0),
    paste0("Count", seq_along(out[-1]))
  )
)
```

where

```
> out1
                Especies Count
1    (Celeus flavescens)     1
2 (Crypturellus tataupa)     4
3         (Piaya cayana)     2

> out2
                Especies Count1 Count2
1    (Celeus flavescens)      0      1
2 (Crypturellus tataupa)      1      3
3         (Piaya cayana)      2      0
```

## data

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Especies = c("(Crypturellus tataupa)", "(Piaya cayana)"
), Conteo = 1:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(Species = c("(Crypturellus tataupa)", "(Celeus flavescens)"
), Count = c(3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, I would suggest renaming the variables in one of your data frames to match the other.

##### df1

```
structure(list(Especies = c("(Crypturellus tataupa)", "(Piaya cayana)"
), Conteo = c(1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

##### df2

```
structure(list(Species = c("(Crypturellus tataupa)", "(Celeus flavescens)"
), Count = c(3, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  rename(Species = Especies,
         Count = Conteo)
```

#### Output 1

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  summarize(Count = sum(Count),
            .by = Species)
#>                  Species Count
#> 1 (Crypturellus tataupa)     4
#> 2         (Piaya cayana)     2
#> 3    (Celeus flavescens)     1
```

#### Output 2

```
full_join(df1, df2, join_by(Species)) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Count'), ~replace_na(., 0)))
#>                  Species Count.x Count.y
#> 1 (Crypturellus tataupa)       1       3
#> 2         (Piaya cayana)       2       0
#> 3    (Celeus flavescens)       0       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest you to keep same name for common columns (species), this is a good habit to avoid mistakes.

**OUTPUT**

**First output**

I suggest you to use full_join changing the name of count columns and change NAs value by zero values.

```
df <- df1 %>% rename(count1=count) %>% full_join(df2 %>% rename(count2=count),by="species") %>% mutate_all(~ ifelse(is.na(.x),0,.x))
df
species count1 count2
1       F     10      5
2       E      8      3
3       B      3      6
4       C      7      0
5       D     10      3
6       A      0      4
```

**Second output**

Easy to apply a sum of columns *count1* and *count2*

```
df %>% mutate(count = count1 + count2) %>% select(species,count)
species count
1       F    15
2       E    11
3       B     9
4       C     7
5       D    13
6       A     4
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- data.frame(species=sample(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),5,replace=FALSE),count=sample(seq(1,10),5,replace=TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(species=sample(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),5,replace=FALSE),count=sample(seq(1,10),5,replace=TRUE))
```